# Data Extraction from PDF to Text File

Tags: python, text-extraction

I have multiple pdf in a folder. I merge all the pdfs and run this code:

```
    doc = fitz.open(merged.pdf)
    out = open('raw.txt', "wb")
    for page in doc:
        text = page.get_text().encode("utf8")  
        out.write(text)
        out.write(bytes((12,))) 
    out.close()
```

To skip the merging of Pdfs this code was arrived:

```
from glob import glob
import os

x = "/path"

for pdf in glob(x + os.sep + '*.pdf'):
    
    doc = fitz.open(pdf)  # open document
    out = open('raw.txt', "wb")
    for page in doc:
        text = page.get_text().encode("utf8")  
        out.write(text)
        out.write(bytes((12,))) 
    out.close()
```

However, only one PDF was captured. I would like to have the same output on first code mentioned.

Comment: i have tried the open(".txt",a) but give me this error:                                                     write() argument must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 0):

To write to an open file use `out.write()`

```py
with open('.txt','wb') as out:
    out.write(data)
```

As you are saving to a textfile you do not need to open it in binary mode "wb" or "rb". But I guess there is no harm as you are most likely only going to get garble when using open() on a pdf(?)